# Drag and drop divs using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a simple task manager where tasks are regrouped by steps. Therefore, many steps can have many tasks. Currently, I have my angularJS model mapped properly. What I want to do right now is to be able to reorder the divs representing the steps.

For example, if I have three steps named 1,3,2 I want to be able to drag the step 2 and move it above step 3 therefore putting them in the order 1,2,3. To do so, I would have to modify my angularJs model accordingly.

What I have currently, is that the ui is responding, I can see the step changing positions, but my the array containing all the steps stays in the same order... Is there a way to reorder this array or at least a way to get the new position of the step ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/bjsgQz?p=preview

Comment: please put your code here not only error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using [ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable); I've used it on one of my own projects for allowing drag-and-drop reordering, and it's worked rather well. I should point out that it does have a dependency on JQuery/JQueryUI (for the sortable widget), but it was worth it for us.

Comment: I used it and I can move the div around. My problem is that when I move the divs I mean when I reorder them, it is not mapped to the AngularJS model...

Comment: That's odd; when we've used it it's behaved in exactly that manner: when you move an element that is a child element of one with the ui-sortable directive (in our case the children were created using an ng-repeat), the reordering was immediately reflected in the scope. In fact, I just went to your Plunker example and am seeing the re-ordering behavior reflected in the little "scope viewer" at the bottom of the preview pane. Could this be a browser issue?

Comment: Aha! I just noticed that if you add a task to a step, it breaks.

Comment: I think I may have it: it looks like you're missing an ng-model on your sortable ng-repeat for tasks. If I add 'ng-model="step.tasks"' to that ng-repeat, the scope updates properly even after adding a task.

Comment: About the "scope viewer", are you talking about the one I created using <pre> tags ? I saw that it is reordering in Opera but not in chrome or safari on a mac...

Comment: Correct. I saw it updating the content of your JSON block under IE11 and Chrome until I added a task, at which point it broke. After adding the ng-model directive I mentioned above, it worked even after adding a task.